# Is eachLine() sufficient to keep a process from blocking?

Tags: groovy

In a Groovy script, is the eachLine closure sufficient to keep a process from blocking due to a full buffer?

Comment: Can you explain your question in a bit more detail? I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: See Process.consumeProcessOutput() Groovy JDK documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it depends from the different complexities of the the two processes.

I guess that one is the one that produces output, while the other one consumes it with `eachLine`. Then if the second one has enough CPU time to prevent the buffer from filling, you won't have any block. Otherwise it will slowly/fastly fill until there is no room anymore.

There is no general answer in your case since it depends from the processing done by `eachLine` and the one made by the other process which produces data.

Comment: Ok so that indirectly answers my question. As long as the line is less than the buffer size, then the process will not block.